# Systemtap error on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, systemtap

after install systemtap on ubuntu,test example hello-stap.stp。but there are some errors。

how can I fix this?

thanks

systemtap version

> Systemtap translator/driver (version 2.9/0.165, Debian version 2.9-2ubuntu2 (xenial))
>
> Copyright (C) 2005-2015 Red Hat, Inc. and others
>
> This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
>
> enabled features: AVAHI LIBSQLITE3 NLS NSS TR1_UNORDERED_MAP

hello-stap.stp

```
probe begin
{
    print("hello world\n")
    exit()
}
```

this is error info。

Error 1:

> In file included from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/linux/runtime.h:204:0,
>                           from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/runtime.h:24,
>                           from /tmp/stapd8LhT7/stap_24feca2d4e5abb002d28b0bc184e6d61_945_src.c:25:
>           /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/linux/access_process_vm.h: In function ‘__access_process_vm_’:
>           /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/linux/access_process_vm.h:35:29: error: passing argument 1 of ‘get_user_pages’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Werror=int-conversion]
>               ret = get_user_pages (tsk, mm, addr, 1, write, 1, &page, &vma);
>                   ^

Comment: other error info

Comment: You should ask this question in https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: @Memduh Çağrı Demir thx I add a question https://askubuntu.com/questions/952874/systemtap-ubuntu-error/952875#952875。

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, so I end up building systemtap from source. I am using v3.1 on xenial, and so far so good.

```
## Install build-required packages
apt-get update && \
        apt-get install -y build-essential gettext elfutils libdw-dev python wget tar && \
        apt-get clean;

## Build from source
wget https://sourceware.org/systemtap/ftp/releases/systemtap-3.1.tar.gz
tar xzvf systemtap-3.1.tar.gz

## Instruction: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=systemtap.git;a=blob_plain;f=README;hb=HEAD
cd systemtap-3.1/ && \
         ./configure && \
         make all && \
         make install ;
```

Comment: Try your method but still simple script could not be compiled correctly.

Comment: Sorry It works except that systemtap-4.0.tar.gz will works . Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue myself. In short, Ubuntu's systemtap package is currently out of date.

**Explanation:** Sometime ago, the kernel updated the get_user_pages() function, which meant anything using the previous function prototype now failed to compile. This also happened on VMWare's vmmon and vmnet modules. When you run stap, it generates a kernel module source file that uses get_user_pages(), compiles it and loads it into the kernel. But the C code it generates uses the old function definition and therefore fails to build.

**Currently no Solution:** You can either build SystemTap from source (which I failed to do, but I also did not try very hard) or tell Ubuntu to upgrade their broken systemtap package - I submitted a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemtap/+bug/1718537), maybe you can confirm it.

My solution was to switch to Fedora 26 and run /usr/bin/stap-prep to install the pre-requisites. Worked without any hiccups!

Comment: yes build systemtap from newest source version could help