# Systemtap Ubuntu 22.04.2 compile error: static declaration of ‘proc_set_user’ follows non-static declaration

Tags: ubuntu, systemtap

I have installed `systemtap` following their [Ubuntu tutorial](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/wiki/SystemtapOnUbuntu). I took my kernel debug symbols following [Ubuntu's wiki tutorial](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Debug%20Symbol%20Packages). Since I have SecureBoot enabled, I am "using" a compile server (hosted on my machine, same as the one on which I plan on executing the `stap` (`localhost`) ). Running `-l` "scripts" (e.g.: `$ sudo stap -l 'syscall.*' --use-server=localhost`) works fine, as only 3 of the 5 passes are needed.

The problem occurs when requesting a very simple probe: `sudo stap -e 'probe begin {exit()}' --use-server=localhost`. At pass 4 (compiling the generated C code), I get various errors:

```
In file included from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/transport/procfs.c:13,
                 from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/transport/transport.c:72,
                 from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/linux/print.c:17,
                 from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/print.c:17,
                 from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/runtime_context.h:22,
                 from <server>/stap000000/stap_44621a3e20f38e1a82b1cb20ff27737b_949_src.c:49:
/usr/share/systemtap/runtime/proc_fs_compatibility.h:29:13: error: static declaration of ‘proc_set_user’ follows non-static declaration
   29 | static void proc_set_user(struct proc_dir_entry *de, kuid_t uid, kgid_t gid)
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/linux/runtime.h:22,
                 from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/runtime.h:26,
                 from <server>/stap000000/stap_44621a3e20f38e1a82b1cb20ff27737b_949_src.c:21:
./include/linux/proc_fs.h:112:13: note: previous declaration of ‘proc_set_user’ with type ‘void(struct proc_dir_entry *, kuid_t,  kgid_t)’
  112 | extern void proc_set_user(struct proc_dir_entry *, kuid_t, kgid_t);
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/transport/procfs.c:13,
                 from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/transport/transport.c:72,
                 from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/linux/print.c:17,
                 from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/print.c:17,
                 from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/runtime_context.h:22,
                 from <server>/stap000000/stap_44621a3e20f38e1a82b1cb20ff27737b_949_src.c:49:
/usr/share/systemtap/runtime/proc_fs_compatibility.h: In function ‘proc_set_user’:
/usr/share/systemtap/runtime/proc_fs_compatibility.h:31:11: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct proc_dir_entry’
   31 |         de->uid = __kuid_val(uid);
      |           ^~
/usr/share/systemtap/runtime/proc_fs_compatibility.h:32:11: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct proc_dir_entry’
   32 |         de->gid = __kgid_val(gid);
      |           ^~
 proc_remove
/usr/share/systemtap/runtime/proc_fs_compatibility.h:47:13: error: static declaration of ‘proc_remove’ follows non-static declaration
   47 | static void proc_remove(struct proc_dir_entry *de)
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/linux/runtime.h:22,
                 from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/runtime.h:26,
                 from <server>/stap000000/stap_44621a3e20f38e1a82b1cb20ff27737b_949_src.c:21:
./include/linux/proc_fs.h:124:13: note: previous declaration of ‘proc_remove’ with type ‘void(struct proc_dir_entry *)’
  124 | extern void proc_remove(struct proc_dir_entry *);
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/transport/procfs.c:13,
                 from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/transport/transport.c:72,
                 from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/linux/print.c:17,
                 from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/print.c:17,
                 from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/runtime_context.h:22,
                 from <server>/stap000000/stap_44621a3e20f38e1a82b1cb20ff27737b_949_src.c:49:
/usr/share/systemtap/runtime/proc_fs_compatibility.h: In function ‘proc_remove’:
/usr/share/systemtap/runtime/proc_fs_compatibility.h:49:21: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct proc_dir_entry’
   49 |         if (de && de->subdir == NULL) {
      |                     ^~
/usr/share/systemtap/runtime/proc_fs_compatibility.h:50:36: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct proc_dir_entry’
   50 |                 if (atomic_read(&de->count) != LAST_ENTRY_COUNT)
      |                                    ^~
In file included from ./include/asm-generic/bug.h:22,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/bug.h:87,
                 from ./include/linux/bug.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/mmdebug.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/gfp.h:5,
                 from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/linux/runtime_defines.h:20,
                 from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/runtime_defines.h:8,
                 from <server>/stap000000/stap_44621a3e20f38e1a82b1cb20ff27737b_949_src.c:12:
/usr/share/systemtap/runtime/proc_fs_compatibility.h:54:34: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct proc_dir_entry’
   54 |                                de->name);
      |                                  ^~
./include/linux/printk.h:436:33: note: in definition of macro ‘printk_index_wrap’
  436 |                 _p_func(_fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__);                           \
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/share/systemtap/runtime/proc_fs_compatibility.h:51:25: note: in expansion of macro ‘printk’
   51 |                         printk(KERN_ERR "Removal of %s from /proc"
      |                         ^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/transport/procfs.c:13,
                 from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/transport/transport.c:72,
                 from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/linux/print.c:17,
                 from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/print.c:17,
                 from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/runtime_context.h:22,
                 from <server>/stap000000/stap_44621a3e20f38e1a82b1cb20ff27737b_949_src.c:49:
/usr/share/systemtap/runtime/proc_fs_compatibility.h:55:37: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct proc_dir_entry’
   55 |                 remove_proc_entry(de->name, de->parent);
      |                                     ^~
/usr/share/systemtap/runtime/proc_fs_compatibility.h:55:47: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct proc_dir_entry’
   55 |                 remove_proc_entry(de->name, de->parent);
      |                                               ^~
```

The full error log, as well as more information, can be found in the output of running `stap-report`, hosted [here](https://pastebin.com/vPRXMHzv).

A warning that might be of importance in the file (though I doubt it) is :

```
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0
  You are using:           gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0
```

Given I have started my server with `-B "-e CC=/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc"`, I don't exactly know how to fix it without changing my whole system's CC environment variable.

It does not seem to be the same problem as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46047270/systemtap-error-on-ubuntu), as that bug [seems to have been fixed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemtap/+bug/1830226).
I am under Linux kernel `5.19.0-32-generic`

Would anyone know what causes the problem, or how to solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Guy, the problem caused by the outdated systemtap version on ubuntu-22.04. Ubuntu apt's newest version is systemtap-4.2, which do not support linux kernel-5.19.

To solve the problem, we have install to a newer systemtap version. I found this resource:

[https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-support-team/+archive/ubuntu/systemtap](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-support-team/+archive/ubuntu/systemtap)

It's tracking upstream systemtap release and contains the most recently systemtap official version 5.0.

I installed the systemtap-5.0 and the problem solved.

One more thing, you'd better run command: `sudo stap-prep` to     check if your local environment is satisfied to running stap.

Hope above solutions will help you!